# Why are there non-system users snap_daemon and snapd-range-524287-root with same rights as root user?

Tags: ubuntu, users, root, snap

Who are `snap_daemon` and `snapd-range-524287-root` users, I didn't add, as shown in /etc/passwd, added as regular root users ( by `snapd` program? by Canonical ), who have the same `sudo` rights as my root user and why is this allowed and how is this not a security risk?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these users are users added by the installation of the snapd daemon.

It's very usual to give daemons special users to isolate their privileges.

Some daemons need more privileges than others. So, yeah, that's a security risk, but less of a security risk than running `snapd` as root.

Not sure what you mean with "same `sudo` rights as my root user": The root user doesn't need `sudo`; it's already root.

Comment: Could snap Firefox update itself without permission?

Comment: What does that have to do with your question post here?

Comment: That would mean it can do more than me, the owner of the machine.

Comment: … like hundreds of other programs on your machine. But it's not firefox that updates *itself*, it's snapd updating firefox.

Comment: When I write sudo apt upgrade Firefox, I follow some rules. A command is a rule in OS. Also, when I am part of developer group, I follow some rules. But these snap users could be doing secret updates without my knowledge or someone else's knowledge of Linux community to check the code.

Comment: apt could be doing secret things (and hint: is doing update checking in background, and depending on how you configure it, automatic upgrades). What's your point?